# Law of total covariance

Tags: statistics, covariance

The question is:

Let $X,Y,Z$ be 3 random variables ; show  that

$$Cov(X,Y∣Z) = E(XY∣Z)-E(X∣Z)E(Y∣Z)$$

So I started from the LHS :

$Cov(X,Y∣Z) = E[(X-E(X∣Z))(Y-E(Y∣Z))∣Z] = E[[XY+E(X∣Z)E(Y∣Z)-XE(X∣Z)-YE(Y∣Z)] ∣ Z] = E(XY∣Z)+E[E(X∣Z)E(Y∣Z)∣Z]-E[XE(Y∣Z)∣Z]-E[YE(X∣Z)∣Z]$

and i'm lost here

Is that $E[XE(Y∣Z)∣Z] = E[X∣Z]E[Y∣Z]$?
and $E[E(X∣Z)E(Y∣Z)∣Z] = E[X∣Z]E[Y∣Z]$?

Comment: Correction that should be Cov(X,Y∣Z) = E(XY∣Z)-E(X∣Z)E(Y∣Z)

Comment: I have integrated your correction into your question.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
Cov(X,Y|Z) &= E[(X-E(X|Z))(Y-E(Y|Z))|Z] \\
&= E[XY - XE[Y|Z] - YE[X|Z] + E[X|Z]E[Y|Z] \;|\; Z]\\
&= E[XY|Z] - E[X|Z]E[Y|Z] - E[Y|Z]E[X|Z] + E[X|Z]E[Y|Z]\\
&= E[XY|Z] - E[X|Z]E[Y|Z]\\
\end{align}

Hope that helps!